# Is it possible for dictionary key-value pairs to switch themselves and remove themselves, as in following example?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
k = {True:1,1:'no',1.0:'maybe'}
print(k)
```

Output:

```
{True: 'maybe'}
```

It was first time a saw something like this.

Why Someone explain this thing, I am new to Python.

Comment: Try `1 == 1.0 == True`